# Creating a DIR list and adding text

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, batch-processing

I am trying to create a batch that can add a text in front of each line.

My batch looks like this:

```
dir /b /s /a-d-r /o:gen >%temp%\file_list.txt
start notepad++ %temp%\file_list.txt
```

The current output txt looks like :

> C:\miscellaneous_fixes\materials\decals\manhackcut1.vtf
>
> C:\miscellaneous_fixes\materials\decals\manhackcut2.vtf
>
> etc...

Which is very close to what I need, but I would like the batch to add the text " **-include,**" and have the final txt like this:

> -include,C:\miscellaneous_fixes\materials\decals\manhackcut1.vtf
>
> -include,C:\miscellaneous_fixes\materials\decals\manhackcut2.vtf
>
> etc...

**Note :** a space before each "-include," is important or else my other program cant read the file.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```bat
@echo off
>%temp%\file_list.txt (
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d-r /o:gen') do echo -include,%%a
)
Start notepad++ %temp%\file_list.txt
```